# Zingchart Live Feed View Change

Tags: javascript, view, data-visualization, live-streaming, zingchart

Let me start off by saying I am fairly new to this.

So what I'm currently doing is I'm playing around with the live feed chart using a js function that produces and stringifies random numbers.

```
window.feed = function(callback) {
    var tick = {};

    tick.plot0 = parseInt(10+900*Math.random(), 10);


    callback(JSON.stringify(tick));

};
```

The first issue I'm trying to tackle is being able to switch charts with the click of a button without the feed restarting, essentially having the feed function running in the back and (I'd assume) storing the data into an array? Would that be the correct approach? But currently, when I click the button it just restarts the feed. Here's the code:

```
$('#chartButton').bind('click', function(){
    zingchart.exec('chart', 'setdata',{
        'data': {
            'type': 'bar',
            "refresh":{
        "type":"feed",
        "transport":"js",
        "url":"feed()",
        "interval":200
    },
            'series':[
            {
        'values':[]
        //[11,26,7,44,11]
    },
    {
        'values':[]
        //[42,13,21,15,33]
    }

            ]
        }
    });
});

$('#lineButton').bind('click', function(){
    zingchart.exec('chart', 'setdata',{
        'data': {
            'type': 'line',
            "refresh":{
        "type":"feed",
        "transport":"js",
        "url":"feed()",
        "interval":200
    },
            'series':[
            {
        'values':[]
        // [11,26,7,44,11]
    },
    {
        'values':[]
        // [42,13,21,15,33]
    }
            ]
        }
    });
});

$('#areaButton').bind('click', function(){
    zingchart.exec('chart', 'setdata',{
        'data': {
            'type': 'area',
            "refresh":{
        "type":"feed",
        "transport":"js",
        "url":"feed()",
        "interval":200
    },
            'series':[
                {
                'values':[]
                // [11,26,7,44,11]
                },
                {
                'values':[]
                // [42,13,21,15,33]
                }
            ]
        }

    });
});
```

And lastly, I'm trying to make it so it has two different "values" being displayed on the chart, but I can't seem to figure out how I would do that. The tutorial says *if* you're going to use two values inputs create the objects, but doesn't extrapolate on how to get the different values transmuted.

My hunch is that I create the feed function, but store all the values being created into an array, one for each function. Then assign those arrays to be the values of the chart, but I've been having trouble figuring out exactly how to increment through an array in javascript so you can keep adding more and more data to it as it is created. Any help would be much appreciated.